# How to add antd to Nextjs

Tags: sass, next.js, antd

I create a project base on [with-ant-design-less](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-ant-design-less) and then try to add sass to project. I change the following files:

next.config.js:

```
/* eslint-disable */
const withSass = require("@zeit/next-sass");
const withLess = require("@zeit/next-less");
const lessToJS = require("less-vars-to-js");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

// Where your antd-custom.less file lives
const themeVariables = lessToJS(
  fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "./assets/antd-custom.less"), "utf8")
);

module.exports = withSass({
  cssModules: true,
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    importLoaders: 1,
    localIdentName: "[folder]_[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
  },
  ...withLess({
    lessLoaderOptions: {
      javascriptEnabled: true,
      modifyVars: themeVariables, // make your antd custom effective
    },
    webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
      if (isServer) {
        const antStyles = /antd\/.*?\/style.*?/;
        const origExternals = [...config.externals];
        config.externals = [
          (context, request, callback) => {
            if (request.match(antStyles)) return callback();
            if (typeof origExternals[0] === "function") {
              origExternals[0](context, request, callback);
            } else {
              callback();
            }
          },
          ...(typeof origExternals[0] === "function" ? [] : origExternals),
        ];

        config.module.rules.unshift({
          test: antStyles,
          use: "null-loader",
        });
      }
      return config;
    },
  }),
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "with-ant-design-less",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-less": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "antd": "^3.5.4",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.7.0",
    "less": "3.0.4",
    "less-vars-to-js": "1.3.0",
    "next": "latest",
    "null-loader": "2.0.0",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^13.13.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  }
}
```

but when I run the project I get the following error:

```
[ error ] ./pages/index.module.scss
To use Next.js' built-in Sass support, you first need to install `sass`.
Run `npm i sass` or `yarn add sass` inside your workspace.
```

Although I'm looking for better solution to setup the project because in this way all the style will be in one big chunk that cause performance issue.

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

next.config.js:

```
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const withCss = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withLess = require('@zeit/next-less');
const lessToJS = require('less-vars-to-js');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const lessThemeVariablesFilePath = './static/ant-theme-variables.less';

const themeVariables = lessToJS(
  fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, lessThemeVariablesFilePath), 'utf8'),
);

const lessNextConfig = {
  lessLoaderOptions: {
    javascriptEnabled: true,
    modifyVars: themeVariables,
  },
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (isServer) {
      const antStyles = /antd\/.*?\/style.*?/;
      const origExternals = [...config.externals];
      config.externals = [
        (context, request, callback) => {
          if (request.match(antStyles)) return callback();
          if (typeof origExternals[0] === 'function') {
            origExternals[0](context, request, callback);
          } else {
            callback();
          }
        },
        ...(typeof origExternals[0] === 'function' ? [] : origExternals),
      ];

      config.module.rules.unshift({
        test: antStyles,
        use: 'null-loader',
      });
    }
    return config;
  },
};
const sassNextConfig = {
  cssModules: true,
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    localIdentName: '[path]___[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
  },
};

module.exports = withPlugins([
  [withLess, lessNextConfig],
  [withSass, sassNextConfig],
]);
```

babel config:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['next/babel'],
  plugins: [
    ['import', { libraryName: 'antd', style: true }],
  ],
};
```

I use sass, less and css. it depends on your requirement. and you can add your custom variables in an static file as I did.
hope be helpful.

Comment: thanks but I found out that all I need is to install `node-sass` not the `sass`

Comment: Thanks @SaeedAmin. The above thing was all I needed to do, found this after wasting hours of trail and error.

Comment: looks good, but how can you add a global less/scss file without modules

Answer (score 2):

So, for people who came here just for the **basic addition**, you can add antd to your nextjs app by installing antd

`npm i antd`

and then you can add the antd styles to your

*_app.js* file

after your global styles:

`import 'antd/dist/antd.css'`